# Converting List to String for SQL Array Insert

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm trying to convert an r list containing names into a string for an sql insert for a Postgresql text[] column.

```
name_list <- list("bob smith", "joe bob", "jim bob")
```

The goal is to create an sql insert statement suck as:

```
INSERT INTO players (name) value ({"bob smith", "joe bob", "jim bob"})
```

I've tried:

```
> name_str <- paste('{', unlist(name_list), '}', collapse=", ")
```

Which produces:

```
[1] "{ bob smith }, { joe bob }, { jim bob }"
```

Any thoughts as to how I can produce: {"bob smith", "joe bob", "jim bob"} ?

Answer (score 0):

Try package `glue` which is perfect for string operations like this. Or you can use `paste0` function:

```
paste0('INSERT INTO players (name) value ({',
       paste0('"', name_list, '"', collapse = ', '), '})')
```

but you can always go wit any database-related package to put the values into the db for you

Comment: This is close, but the array needs to have ' appear before and after the {} brackets.  Something like: paste0("INSERT INTO players (name) value('{", paste0('"', name_list, '"', collapse = ", "), "}')")

Comment: are you sure about that? at least it is not stated in your question